# Customise Views PDF export

Tags: views, files

I am using [Views PDF](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_pdf) to export some of my pages as PDF files. So far I can get it to export the files .
I am however getting challenges in trying to adjust the styling. I have looked at the module for any tpl files and they are not there. Anybody with a headstart on this?

Answer (score 1):

In the pdf view under "PDF SETTINGS" you can add a css file for styling. Note that it only supports basic css.